# jQuery UI dialog - Next button reference

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

how do i reference the next button in jQuery UI dialog popup?

I need to change the background colour for the "Next" button when the button is clicked, because Internet Explorer has a glitch that changes the button background colour to blue (because of hover colour) permanently.

The code bit is displayed below

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 'auto',
  position: 'top',
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Cancel": function() {
       $( this ).dialog( "close" );
       allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    },
    "Next": function() {  
       alert('asdf');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What version of IE? Seems fine in 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS classes that apply format to that kind of buttons are:

`ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only`

Maybe you just need a reference to "Next" button to apply specific CSS. Something like this:

```
$('.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonset button:contains("Next")')
```

This selector get all buttons text containing "Next" text inside any JQueryUI Dialog of your HTML.